# Tool to list every e-mail detail sent from a server

Tags: ubuntu, logs, postfix

**Introduction:**

I have a specific problem with an Ubuntu server where some security leak allowed spammers to use the server to send e-mail. I fixed most of the problems (caused by some unsecured Wordpress installations) but I have a feeling that some things are still missing.

In order to deal with spam I installed clamav and run it from time to time, also I have deleted the infected files and I use fail2ban for a series of services to block scanning and bruteforce.

**The question**

Is there any tool that creates a log (other than `mail.log` or `mail.warn`) with every e-mail sent from the server both smtp and script?

Comment: What mail server was this, please? Exim, postfix, sendmail, something else?

Comment: @FaheemMitha this is postfix.

Comment: Postfix should automatically log server activity, including sent messages. I use exim myself.  You could set up a [content filter](http://serverfault.com/questions/183283/how-to-log-full-outgoing-mails-in-postfix).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the spammers bypassed your mail servers entirely and there is no log that there messages were sent.  Any messages sent by postfix should be logged to /var/log/mail.